# PyInstaller Still Requires conda environment to run the the Script

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pyinstaller

I am trying to learn python and created script that split vocals and bass(for learning purpose) and I just want to create easy to run exe that doesn't require anaconda/python to run new systems.
So I used PyInstaller.
If It is repeated Question please give me the link because i can't put the right words to get what i Want.
But, The .exe file still need to run with anaconda Environment.

```
import os
import subprocess
import traceback
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pydub import AudioSegment

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
audio_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()
song_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(audio_file))[0]
try:
    subprocess.run(['demucs', '-d', 'cpu', audio_file])
    print(song_name)
    audio_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "separated", "htdemucs", song_name)
    bass = AudioSegment.from_file(os.path.join(audio_path, "bass.wav"))
    drums = AudioSegment.from_file(os.path.join(audio_path, "drums.wav"))
    other = AudioSegment.from_file(os.path.join(audio_path, "other.wav"))


    combined = bass.overlay(drums).overlay(other)

    combined.export(audio_path+song_name+"vocal_less"+".wav", format="wav")

    with open(audio_file, "rb") as infile, open(os.path.join(audio_path,song_name+"vocals.wav"), "wb") as outfile:
        outfile.write(infile.read())
    os.remove(audio_path+"drums.wav")
    os.remove(audio_path+"bass.wav")
    os.remove(audio_path+"other.wav")
except Exception as e:
    # Log the exception to a file
    with open("error_log.txt", "w") as f:
        traceback.print_exc(file=f)

    # Print the exception to the console
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    # Pause to see the error message before the console window closes
    input("Press Enter to exit.")
```

This is my whole code and create .exe of it. If don't Use conda environmnet . the error shows

Error Outcome:

[image: Error Outcome]

But If run with conda Environment it will execute successfully

Successful Outcome:

[image: Successful Outcome]

Can someone help so i can make this run without installing python or conda

Comment: Did you only install `pydub` inside Conda?   pydub needs demucs needs torchaudio, which needs a C DLL called libtorchaudio.dll.  That's the file it can't find.  If you include that in your executable, it should work.

Comment: Thank you for Looking it in. I Did Install It in the anaconda environment but thing i noticed is .exe file size is only 9megaByte. but demucs alone is 170+ Mb. so the PyInstaller Doesn't get all the dependecies? So How do I add the dependecies is what i need to look for.Now i Can work out with that.

Comment: You can give pyinstaller a list of modules to include that it might have missed.